# Finding the code on which maximum occured

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet as under

```
Name    Code    Date    Profit on particular day        Name    Output
A   2400    1/11/2016   38500       A   Nil
A   2300    1/14/2016   26750       B   1240
A   2200    1/14/2016   21250       C   95
A   2300    1/11/2016   19250           
A   2250    1/14/2016   14000           
A   2100    1/14/2016   11750           
B   1220    1/15/2016   750         
B   1280    1/11/2016   4875            
B   1360    1/12/2016   4875            
B   1380    1/11/2016   4500            
B   1320    1/11/2016   3375            
B   1280    1/12/2016   2250            
B   1340    1/11/2016   2250            
B   1340    1/14/2016   2250            
B   1240    1/15/2016   50000           
B   1260    1/15/2016   0           
C   85  1/14/2016   324000          
C   85  1/13/2016   282000          
C   85  1/11/2016   246000          
C   95  1/15/2016   6000000         
C   90  1/12/2016   156000          
C   90  1/14/2016   138000
```

In the above i want to write a formula such that for example name "A" -search maximum profit , if that profit happened to be on date the maximum among the dates, then give code as mentioned in column two.For example for name  "A" maximum profit is 38500 which happens on 1/11/2016 which is not latest date among the date column against name "A" so output is nil.For name "B" maximum profit is 50000 which occurs on 01/15/2016 which happens to be on latest date among date column against name B so output is content of code column i.e. 1240.

Comment: So, your expectation is, if date is latest date, then show max data for specific name, otherwise show Nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) makes quick work of pseudo-MINIFS/MAXIFS with single or multiple conditions.

In H2 as a standard formula,

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, B$2:B$23/((A$2:A$23=G2)*
                                    (C$2:C$23=AGGREGATE(14, 6, C$2:C$23/(A$2:A$23=G2), 1))*
                                    (D$2:D$23=AGGREGATE(14, 6, D$2:D$23/(A$2:A$23=G2), 1))), 1)
         ,"nil")
```

[image: aggregate_minifs_maxifs]
            <sup>[AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) as MINIFS and MAXIFS</sup>

**[Dynamic ranging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGtlO.png)**

The above formula can be improved to automatically compensate for new data added to the bottom of the existing formula with the following modifications.

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))/((A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))=G2)*
     (C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))=AGGREGATE(14, 6, C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))/(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))=G2), 1))*
     (D$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))=AGGREGATE(14, 6, D$2:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))/(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))=G2), 1))), 1)
  ,"nil")
```

[image: aggregate_minifs_maxifs_dynamic_range]
            <sup>[AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) with dynamic ranging</sup>

Comment: Thanks a Lot.You are a Genius.

Comment: Sir, Your formula is just superb.If you can help further that number of rows in the data are limited to 23 where as in my case the number of rows will be added each day so not limited to 23.Can you please help further?.Regards

Comment: There is a method I use to automatically isolate expanding data that improves calculation time. I do not usually provide it because while efficient, it looks messy and no one understands it. I will add it above but I'm not going to write pages of information trying to explain it. If you need an explanation, I have provided explanations on this site in other questions many times.

Comment: Thanks and Regard.Many thanks from the depth of my heart.

Comment: Dear Sir,Can you please help further, i am having a problem when the content of the column 2 "code"  is non numeric but is a text.The above formula in case of code being a text is giving:nil in all cases .Thanks @Jeeped

Comment: Changing the conditions of a question sufficiently that valid answers are no longer valid is considered bad forum etiquette. I would recommend leaving this question as it is and starting a new one where you can supply all of the new information in a fresh format. See [Etiquette for Russian Doll Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions).

Comment: I am extremely Sorry for this.Thanks